# How to create a different contract for private and ICO?

Tags: contract-development, ico, crowdsale, presale

Is it possible that the Total supply is created at the time of creation of token for Privete-sale and then create an ICO contract for the Unsold tokens to sell them on crowdsale?

(i.e. It is hard to predict that how many tokens will be sold during Private sale (manual transfers by owner))

Comment: Plz mark my ans is accepted, if you feel ans is relevant and giving some direction towards your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a logic for that. Usefully total number of tokens are fixed. But if you want to change dynamically then you can. Its just method which returns the value. It's more like exchange will accept as a ico or not.

Find below code snippet

```
contract ABCComapny{
   bool private isICOEnabled = false;
   uint256 private TOTAL_NUMBER_TOKENS = 10000000000;
   uint256 private SOLD_TOKENS = 10000000000;

   function getTotalTokens() public returns(uint256){
         if(isICOEnabled){
               return TOTAL_NUMBER_TOKENS - SOLD_TOKENS;
         }
        returns TOTAL_NUMBER_TOKENS;
   }
}
```

When before ICO. You need to check deposit() if isICOEnabled is false then update SOLD_TOKENS.

When your planing to start ico then update isICOEnabled true. But be careful. Run the test cases. Before deployed in mainnet.

Comment: Can you write a smart contract for us to launch an ICO?

Comment: @Jignesh, Please message me, with your contact details.

Comment: nim.jignesh13@gmail.com